# how to remove white space when image loading?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My phone-gap app getting output I have 4 images  sliding automatically it fixed any Device height and width my problem is while sliding images, I am getting white screen before image loading 
my code is :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://responsiveslides.com/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .caption {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 2000;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-shadow: none
        color: #fff;
        background: #000;
        background: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        /*margin: -2;
        margin-top:-70px;*/
        max-width: none;
    }
    img {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .one{ 
        float:right
    }
    html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .ui-content {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });

    $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){       
        setHeight();
    });

    function setHeight() {
        $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-content').height(getRealContentHeight());
        $.mobile.activePage.find('img').height(getRealContentHeight()-4);   
    }

    function getRealContentHeight() {
        var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
        var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
        var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
        var viewport_height = $(window).height();

        var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight() -2;
        if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
            content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
        } 
        return content_height;
    }
</script>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">            
    <div data-role="content" class="slideshow">
        <div id="container">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="" height="100%" width="auto"/><br/>
            <div  class="caption"> <font color="white">Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="http://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a></div>

        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >First Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >three Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <img src="4.jpg" alt=""/><br/>
            <div class="caption"><font color="white" >fourth Second dfasdfasasdasdasdna asdasdasdasd asdasdasd asdasd<br/> asdasdasd asdadasd asdasdad</font><a href="G:\html practise phonegap\responsive\validationform.html" style="text-decoration: none">&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="white"><span class="one">skip</span></font></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script>


$(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(".slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
        var currentSlide = $('.slideshow > div:visible:first'),
            nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

        currentSlide.fadeOut(1)
        nextSlide.fadeIn(2000);

        if ((currentSlide.index() + 1) == 4) {


       Redirect();

        }
    },  2000);
    function Redirect() {
        window.location="https://www.google.co.in";
    }
});

</script>
</html>
```

My code is working nice but when image sliding first white screen will be displayed and then images display

How to hide the white screen?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rXU9y/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a know issue running around for a while.This is due to jquery default page transition effects.https://forum.jquery.com/topic/transition-flashing-showing-white-page-between-pages

The work around I did was the following code in my js .It worked.Hope it works for you too

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
});
```

Just try overwritting transition effect as per your jQM version

Comment: could you please tell me where to place this code in My Html file. as my Js file is taking from Google i am not getting idea when does the transitions effect going on

Comment: try adding it inside the script tag at the bottom of your html page inside the body tag

Comment: i am tried as you said like<body>mycode ......$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
}); </body> but white space are not removed Please give any idea about removing white Space

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem in jQuery Mobile and turning backface visibility off helps to solve this problem to an extent. As per [jQuery Mobile Docs](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/transitions/)

> Some platforms currently have issues with transitions. We are working
>   on a solution to solve the problem for everyone. If you are
>   experiencing flickers and flashes during or at the end of a transition
>   we suggest the following workaround. Please note that this workaround
>   should be thoroughly tested on the target platform before deployment.
>   This workaround is known to cause performance issues and browser
>   crashes on some platforms, especially Android. Add the following code
>   to your custom css.

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
```

> Only seeing fade transitions? To view all transition types, you must
>   be on a browser that supports 3D transforms. By default, devices that
>   lack 3D support (such as Android 2.x) will fallback to "fade" for all
>   transition types. This behavior is configurable (see below).