# how to remove white page when my image redirected in jquery-moblie

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am new to jQuery mobile I have done automatically image sliding but when image loading at first image to second image 
before second image loading first display white Screen and then second image will be displayed 
like same as Second image to threed first white Screen will be loading and then Image displayed So please give me any idea about how to remove white Screen when image loading

[how to remove white space when image loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670417/how-to-remove-white-space-when-image-loading)

Comment: pre-fetch images. Keep next image downloaded even before user slides to it.

Comment: @Gaurav thanks for Reply please see my code 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23670417/how-to-remove-white-space-when-image-loading 
and then Please give me any idea about how to remove white screen

Comment: replied to your question in the link.

Comment: @Gaurav k Please give me idea about Removing White Screen

Comment: Please check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/23799005/1121498

Comment: @Gaurav Thanks for reply i placed .ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; } on my file and then run code on IOS simulator but white screen will be appeared on before image Loading